# JSON_SET, update with another json

Tags: mysql

I have the following json structure inside the column `person_data`:

```
{"name":"john","surname":"smith"}
```

Now, I'd like to update with json of his hobbies:

```
$hobbies = {"c1":"cycling","c2":"swimming"};
```

Mysql:

```
UPDATE people 
SET person_data = JSON_SET(person_data, '$.hobbies', $hobbies) 
WHERE id='1';
```

But the problem is, that it gets inserted as string under `$.hobbies`

I alsow tried with:

```
JSON_SET(person_data, 
         '$.hobbies','',
         '$.hobbies.c1','cycling',
         '$.hobbies.c2','swimming');
```

But all i get is `"hobbies":""`

What I want is:

```
"hobbies": {"c1":"cycling","c2":"swimming"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible ways.

Use [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to create a JSON object from attributes and their values:

```
JSON_SET(
  person_data, 
  '$.hobbies',
  JSON_OBJECT('c1', 'cycling', 'c2', 'swimming')
)
```

[Cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the JSON string to JSON type:

```
JSON_SET(
  person_data,
  '$.hobbies',
  CAST('{"c1":"cycling","c2":"swimming"}' as JSON)
)
```

Both will create a JSON object like this:

```
{"name": "john", "hobbies": {"c1": "cycling", "c2": "swimming"}, "surname": "smith"}
```

See demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dYjsyWYV36QVMdTWgH7x5A/0)